# Grails local plugins

Tags: grails

I have a problem with the less css resources plugin and I would like to make it a local plugin so that I can modify it without loosing the changes when I do grails clean-all.

So I copy the plugin from target/plugins to a local directory, then point to it using:

grails.plugin.location.'lesscss-resources'     = "../grailsplugins/lesscss-resources-1.3.3"

however, when I do this the plugin stops behaving in the same manner as if it was in the target/plugins directory.

The dependencies.groocy in lesscss-resource-1.1.3 looks like:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.release.scm.enabled = false
grails.project.repos.default = "grailsCentral"
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugins"
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        runtime 'org.lesscss:lesscss:1.3.3'

        test ("org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:0.7.0") {
            export = false
        }
        test ('org.gmock:gmock:0.8.2') {
            export = false
        }
        test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.31.0") {
            exclude 'selenium-server'
            export = false
        }
    }
    plugins {
        test (":spock:0.6") {
            export = false
        }
        test (":geb:0.7.2") {
            export = false
        }
        compile (":resources:1.1.6") {
            export = false
        }
        compile (":hibernate:2.0.0") {
            export = false
        }
        compile (":rest-client-builder:1.0.2") {
            export = false
        }
        compile (":tomcat:2.0.0") {
            export = false
        }
        build(':release:2.0.4', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.2') {
           export = false
        }
    }
}
```

First I get:

```
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:3.6.2 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
```

This is due to the dependency on tomcat:2.0.0. So I comment that one out and get first:

```
Installed plugin hibernate-2.0.0
.............You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [rest-client-builder-1.0.3]. Do you want to downgrade to [rest-client-builder-1.0.2]? [y,n]
```

I click yes, then I get to more problems.

Seriously, when Grails moved over to become so "modular" and maven friendly everything went to hell. Since then the community has just died off.

I liked that the plugins used to be installed locally and treated as local plugins, that way you could always tweak them easily.

Now it is almost impossible.

What does that mean that plugins are downgraded or upgraded? Are any buildconfigs altered? For what plugin does that question apply to?

How can I compile the plugin and run it seamlessly as if it was installed using the target folder.

Comment: "So I copy the plugin from target/plugins to a local directory, then point to it" - did you also remove the dependency on `:lesscss-resources:1.3.3` from your BuildConfig at the same time?  You need to configure it _either_ as an inline plugin _or_ as a dependency, not both at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have tried that and running it as such now. I am trying to migrate the plugin to the newer structure ( using 2.3.7 ) ... create-plugin and move over the files and dependencies to buildconfig. However I still get an error on the dependency of tomcat:2.0.0 ... The org.eclipse thing is still there. How come it only appears when loaded locally?

Comment: Ian, what is up with dependency: runtime 'org.lesscss:lesscss:1.3.3'

It depends on itself?

Comment: That's the `lesscss-resources` _plugin_ depending on the underlying `lesscss` _framework_.

Comment: Ok, I get that last part.. but still the other stuff is a bit messy..

Comment: @IanRoberts Would you say it is safe to remvoe the tomcat:2.0.0 dependency? I have a tomcat:7.0.52.1 and hibernate 3.6.x.z dependency in the main application..

Comment: On run-app I am getting a : You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [hibernate-3.6.10.9]. Do you want to downgrade to [hibernate-2.0.0]

I select no, and then get the error: 

/lesscss-resources/LesscssResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy: 57: unable to resolve class ResourceModule 
 @ line 57, column 37.
                   List currentTypes = new ResourceModule().bundleTypes
                                       ^

1 error

Comment: That's what I'd try next.  I have lots of experience of using inline plugins but only ones I wrote myself - I've never tried moving a published plugin to inline use (and I'm also still back on Grails 2.2.x, we haven't made the move to 2.3 yet).

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks for your help! It is not the first time :) I think I will stop upgrading on 2.3.7. I don't like the introduction of a separate asset directory. I like the idea of keeping the client side of the application in one place and not separating it. I believe the framework should take care of them from there, so 2.3.7 is probably as far as I am going.

Comment: When I change the version of the plugins, I keep getting the question of wether to upgrade or downgrade. But I dont get that question for other inline-plugins that uses them. What does that mean? Nothing in the buildconfigs are actually altered. 

The tomcat problem is repeated in all old plugins when they are pointed to locally.

Comment: @IanRoberts I think the problem is that they have changed the grailsRepo location and its content. 

Do you know how I could stop relying on maven and make sure the application and all plugins are future proof? That is always be able to run it in offline mode, as one used to be able to...

Comment: I was able to resolve it by changing some of the versions of the plugins used for hibernate and tomcat and rest client builder and release plugin].. while upgrading to the new plugin structure...